# Fullcalendar is not syncing with Google Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have done everything according to the documentation provided on https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar

I created a new calendar for this specific purpose.

**I have purposely left the API key and calendarID blank**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='../fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='../fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            googleCalendarApiKey: '',
            events: {
                googleCalendarId: ''
            }

        });
    });

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id='calendar'></div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Solved** Check comments for answer

Comment: any console errors? What about response from the ajax call to google? Does it succeed? Are there any events in the response? Have you actually done any debugging here? Your code is fine, there's nothing we can tell you by just looking at that. Assuming you've set up your google account and calendar correctly, it ought to work...but clearly something is missing. We don't have access to your machine or your account, so we can't debug it for you...only you can do that. If you come back with some information you don't understand, provide it and perhaps it'll be a clue for us.

Comment: Getting 2 warnings
$ was used before it was defined and
Missing 'use strict' statement

Comment: the first one sounds like maybe you didn't include jquery properly or define it. Did it definitely load successfully? Or are they just jsLint warnings though? Not actual errors from the JS engine. Check the rest of what I mentioned re the ajax call

Comment: Many thanks @ADyson. I was able to figure out my mistake after doing the ajax call. It seems gcal.js had an incorrect source and you were spot on with the jsLint warnings. Thanks again

Comment: I did wonder why you seemed to be taking gcal.js from a different folder. I guess you can delete the question if it's just a trivial case of a wrong source declaration.